# How to generate my traveled path using CLLocationManager on google map in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, cllocationmanager

User has to create his own path on google map wherever he move step by step the route is generated.

please have look on my code snippet:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager )manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray )locations
{

    CLLocation* location1 = [locations lastObject];

    if (self.endPointArray == nil)
    {
        self.endPointArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    NSString *pointString=[NSString    stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f",location1.coordinate.latitude,location1.coordinate.longitude];
    [self.endPointArray addObject:pointString];
    NSLog(@"end point array :%@",self.endPointArray);
    GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath path];
    for (int i=0; i<self.endPointArray.count; i++)
    {
        NSArray *latlongArray = [[self.endPointArray objectAtIndex:i]componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@","]];

        [path addLatitude:[[latlongArray objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue] longitude:[[latlongArray objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue]];
    }

    if (self.endPointArray.count>2)
    {
        GMSPolyline *polyline = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
        polyline.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
        polyline.strokeWidth = 3.0f;
        polyline.map = _mapView;
    }
}
```

I have create route with help of above code.but sometimes we get unexpected coordinates from CLLocation. If we are on road (route) it's gives perfect but if we are not on road like in home it gives wrong coordinates

Comment: What issue you are having now?

Comment: One think you need to know is that CLLocation accuracy is near about  +/- 60 for india so it can give location in this range not accurate where you stand

Answer (score 3):

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];
    NSTimeInterval age = -[location.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];
    if (age > 120) return;    // ignore old (cached) updates
    if (location.horizontalAccuracy < 0) return;   // ignore invalid updates
    if(self.oldLocation == nil)
     {
     self.oldLocation = location;
      return
      }
    CLLocationDistance distance = [location distanceFromLocation: self.oldLocation];
    if (distance >= 10 && location.horizontalAccuracy <=20) //you can change 10 to 20 if you want more frequent updates
    {
     // add location to path
        self.oldLocation = location;    // save newLocation for next time
    }
}
```

Try using this code. Its from my project and it works just fine. Use it according to your need. Hope it helps you.